# How to fix weird corner artifacts when baking a normal map?

Tags: texture-baking, bevel, normal-map

I am trying to bake a higher poly mesh onto to this lower poly mesh. the higher poly has rounded corners, and the lower poly mesh has sharp corners. Here is the high poly mesh with beveled corners.

[image]

Although after baking, the corners of my low poly mesh has these weird artifacts that look like this:

[image]

I'm currently using an addon called Simple Bake to create the normal maps but am open to other suggested ways of baking this map.

Does anyone know how to bake without getting these weird artifacts on the corners???

Here is a copy of the [BLEND](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/snjekkaqjm2wqc3/AAAt7IJeaXSqJifdCWikim5xa?dl=0) file.

Comment: if the low-poly has sharp edges, the normal map won't be able to create round edges, it will only add roundness to the sharp edges, is it your problem here?

Comment: @moonboots yeah that's the problem I am having. I'm trying to create rounded edges without actually adding geometry. I want to create the illusion of round edges.

Comment: Yes but the normal map will just add a round shape, it won't hide the sharp edge, so now we see both, like a sharp edge in the middle of a round edge

Comment: @moonboots Is there any way to make the whole thing more smoother with a normal map?

Comment: the normal map will just add 3D details on the surface of the object, these details can be smooth, but the normal map won't be able to make the shape of the object itself rounder, if it has sharp angles you'll still see the sharp angles

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you want to bake the round high-poly onto the sharp low-poly:

[image]

If you then project the normal map onto the low-poly here is the result you'll get. The normal map will just add a round shading, it won't hide the existing sharp edge of the low-poly. Normal maps add 3D details to your object, it won't hide existing 3D reliefs:

[image]